# Angular: how to wait for a variable (string) to be defined before using it to style an element?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to draw two divs (each containing components) that are connected by a line. The line's length depends on the widths of the divs, which I'm accessing using the nativeElement property.

I'm using ngAfterViewInit() to calculate the line's width using the divs' nativeElements. However, the divs are drawn without any line connecting them. It's only after I click on the divs that the line is drawn.

How can I wait for the lineWidth to be ready before updating the length of the line?

Here's the template:

```
<div class="bean-view" (click)="backgroundClick.emit()"> 
  <div class="bean-label-container" *ngIf="showLabels">
    <div class="bean-label" *ngFor="let label of bean.labels">{{label}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bean-icon-container" #beanIconContainerElement>
    <sb-bean-icon [type]="bean.type"></sb-bean-icon>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="bean" class="bean" (click)="contentClick.emit()" #beanElement>
    <sb-bean-content [class.disable-click]="disableContentClick" [bean]="bean"></sb-bean-content>
  </div>
  <div class="bean-complete-marker completion-line" [style.width]="lineWidth"></div>
  <div class="bean-response-wrapper">
    <div class="bean-response" *ngFor="let response of bean.response" (click)="responseClick.emit()" #beanResponseElement>
      <sb-bean-content [bean]="response" [isResponse]="true"></sb-bean-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the component code:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { Bean } from '../../../../shared/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'bean-view',
  templateUrl: './beanView.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beanView.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BeanViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bean: Bean;
  @Input() disableContentClick: Bean;
  @Input() showLabels: boolean;

  @Output() contentClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() responseClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() backgroundClick = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('beanIconContainerElement') beanIconContainerElement;
  @ViewChild('beanElement') beanElement;
  @ViewChild('beanResponseElement') beanResponseElement;

  lineWidth: string = undefined;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lineWidth = this.getWidth();
  }

  getWidth(): string {
    const bound: number = 200;
    const iconWidth: number = this.beanIconContainerElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const beanWidth: number = this.beanElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const width: number = bound - (iconWidth + beanWidth);
    return String(width) + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use setTimeout() and set the timeout to 300 (0.3 seconds)? Not the cleanest solution, but I think it would work in 99.99% of cases

Answer (score 1):

Use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#how-to-use) instead of `style.width` like,

```
<div class="bean-complete-marker completion-line" [ngStyle]="{'width': lineWidth}"></div>
```

Modify your component,

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { Bean } from '../../../../shared/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'bean-view',
  templateUrl: './beanView.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beanView.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BeanViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bean: Bean;
  @Input() disableContentClick: Bean;
  @Input() showLabels: boolean;

  @Output() contentClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() responseClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() backgroundClick = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('beanIconContainerElement') beanIconContainerElement;
  @ViewChild('beanElement') beanElement;
  @ViewChild('beanResponseElement') beanResponseElement;

  _lineWidth: string; // notice the change in variable

  get lineWidth() { return this._lineWidth; }

  set lineWidth(width: string) { this._lineWidth = width; } 

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lineWidth = this.getWidth();
  }

  getWidth(): string {
    const bound: number = 200;
    const iconWidth: number = this.beanIconContainerElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const beanWidth: number = this.beanElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const width: number = bound - (iconWidth + beanWidth);
    return String(width) + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried ngStyle, but running into the same result

Comment: edited my answer, replaced `linewidth` with `getWidth()`. Does that work?

Comment: Just tried, but that is throwing an error. The nativeElements seem to be accessed before they're ready.

Comment: This answer should work if you put some protection for `nativeElement` in `getWidth`. In fact, you could event use the OP original code and template, and put the logic of `getWidth` in a property getter like `public get lineWidth(): number`.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on adding protection for nativeElement and using a property getter?

Comment: I have edited the answer again and re-replaced the `getWidth()` with the `getter` `lineWidth`.

Comment: do you get an error? Or can you make a reproduction link?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the pixels units in the style directive:

```
<div class="bean-complete-marker completion-line" [style.width.px]="lineWidth"></div>
```

In the code, you can remove `ngAfterViewInit` and `getWidth`, and define `lineWidth` as a property getter:

```
public get lineWidth(): number {
    const isBeanIconReady: boolean = this.beanIconContainerElement && this.beanIconContainerElement.nativeElement;
    const isBeanElementReady: boolean = this.beanElement && this.beanElement.nativeElement;
    if (isBeanIconReady && isBeanElementReady) {
        const bound: number = 200;
        const iconWidth: number = this.beanIconContainerElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        const beanWidth: number = this.beanElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        const width: number = bound - (iconWidth + beanWidth);
        return width;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To make sure that the DOM is always up-to-date, remove this line from your component declaration:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Comment: Tried this, but the line is still not drawn until I click on the divs.

Comment: Remove this line from the component declaration: `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

Comment: Disabled the changeDetection line. I still have to click to draw the lines, but now, clicking will draw all of the required lines, as opposed to having to draw one line at a time.

Comment: If you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in other components, remove these lines also.

Comment: I removed these lines in every other component, and am still running into the same issue.